# Rspec testing AR model concern within described_class or DummyClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've got AR model concern Uuidable that looks like this:

```
module Uuidable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_create :generate_uuid
  end

  protected

  def generate_uuid
    self.uuid = #some code
  end

end
```

So far I've written `shared_examples_for Uuidable` that looks like this:

```
shared_examples_for Uuidable do

  let(:model) { FactoryGirl.build(described_class) }

  it { expect(model).to callback(:generate_uuid).before(:create) }

  describe '#generate_uuid' do

    it { expect{model.save}.to change {model.uuid} }

    it 'should not generate same uuid' do
      allow(SecureRandom).to receive(:uuid).and_return("c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85", "c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85", "e93f0130-3a81-406f-8871-609d89ae0850")
      model.save
      expect(FactoryGirl.create(described_class).uuid).not_to eq(model.uuid)
    end

    context 'generated uuid field' do
      before(:each) { model.save }
      it { expect(model.uuid).to be_kind_of(String) }
      it { expect(model.uuid).to match(/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i)}
    end

  end

end
```

So... I'm wondering is it fine to test `#generate_uuid` method behaviour within every `Uuidable` model?

Second option I was thinking about was to create tests `Uuidable` concern within `class DummyClass < ActiveRecord::Base` and for `shared_examples` leave only `it { expect(model).to callback(:generate_uuid).before(:create) }`
What do you think ? What's best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer the first option. Assume the case where your another model has some validations, before_save, or before_create callbacks which won't let save the data to table?

By using shared_examples_for you can easily distribute required piece of specs to be tested for `Uuidable` concern used in such models classes.

On the other hand, if you use the second approach, it will be restricted to just one model: `DummyClass`, and probably pass its specs every time regardless the validation or other callbacks failure in models using `Uuidable` module.

Your approach is correct. Just use `it_behaves_like "Uuidable"` in models' specs which uses this concern and let them be run in isolation.